# "no mail for admin", trying to send mail from command-line

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, email

I reinstalled Postfix, reconfigured it, and yet I'm getting this message when I use the `mail` program to start sending a new email.

```
admin@mail:~$ mail
No mail for admin
```

Any tip what I should look for?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To send mail via the commandline, use mail:

```
$ mail -s "Some Subject" admin
Type some stuff
.
```

The dot tells mail the message is finished. You can also redirect program output to mail, or send a file's contents.

```
$ cat /etc/motd | mail -s "Message of the day" admin
$ mail -s "Message of the day" admin < /etc/motd
```

Will both send the contents of /etc/motd to the admin user on the local system. You can send mail out to the internet as well.

```
$ tail -10 /var/log/mail.info | mail -s "Some mail logs for you" admin@example.com
```

Comment: Dang that was fast, you really like to earn points dont cha? ;) Anyway, i'll check it and give you my feedback.

Comment: My superuser bookmark goes to the "Questions -> Newest", I happened to open it to check something else and saw this question :-).

Comment: Sorry, perhaps I misguided you. I don't want to check for mail, just SEND mail. With the mail command a send mail CLI interface should emerge, backed by postfix.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to write the mail, n00b mistake, my bad.

Comment: So, SOLUTION:

If you want to write some mail in the CLI, do this:

mail destination@address.com

Just typing mail checks your mail. :)

Comment: Some updates to clarify your question's intent, and I updated the answer.

Comment: WTF you edited my topic! LOL. Anyway,  good answer, i'll give you some points for your time.